# Using the interesting/ignored tags to filter job ads

Tags: feature-request, tags, advertising, ignored-tags

On SO, the Job Listings are given pretty high prominence on the page, yet they are not targeted very well.

If my "ignored tags" are `osx`, `*iphone*` and `mac`, you've got a pretty sure bet going that I'm not going to be that interested in the iPhone developer position in San Francisco...